# PLSQL creating function that add all values from column and insert the sum into new column

Tags: function, plsql

```
CREATE TABLE WORK(
WorkerNo    NUMBER(10)  NOT NULL,
TotalSalary  NUMBER(10),
CONSTRAINT WORK_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (WorkerNo),

INSERT INTO WORK( 1, NULL );
INSERT INTO WORK( 2, NULL );

CREATE TABLE WorkSalary(
City VARCHAR2(30),
Postal VARCHAR2(30),
Salary NUMBER(9)    NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT WorkSalary_PKEY PRIMARY KEY(City,Postal),

INSERT INTO WorkSalary('New York City', '123456', 5000);
INSERT INTO WorkSalary('Washington DC', '154876', 4500);
INSERT INTO WorkSalary('New Jersey', '458741', 3500);
INSERT INTO WorkSalary('Maryland', '487451', 2000);

CREATE TABLE WORKDONE(
WorkerNo NUMBER(10)     NOT NULL,
JobNo NUMBER(2)     NOT NULL,
City VARCHAR2(30)   NOT NULL,
Postal VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT WORKDONE_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (WorkerNo, JobNo),
CONSTRAINT WORKDONE_FKEY1 FOREIGN KEY (WorkerNo) 
    REFERENCES WORK(WorkerNo),
CONSTRAINT WORKDONE_FKEY2 FOREIGN KEY (City)
    REFERENCES WorkSalary(City),
CONSTRAINT WORKDONE_FKEY3 FOREIGN KEY (Postal)
    REFERENCES WorkSalary(Postal) );

INSERT INTO WORKDONE VALUES( 1, 1, 'New York City', '123456');
INSERT INTO WORKDONE VALUES( 1, 2, 'Maryland', '487451');
INSERT INTO WORKDONE VALUES( 1, 3, 'New Jersey', '458741');
INSERT INTO WORKDONE VALUES( 2, 1, 'New Jersey', '458741');
INSERT INTO WORKDONE VALUES( 2, 2, 'New York City', '123456');
INSERT INTO WORKDONE VALUES( 2, 3, 'Washington DC', '154876');
```

i need to create a function that get the sum of all salary the worker had done on table workdone. for example workerno 1 has done 3 job which is shown on workdone table. i need to get the salary for each work he had done according to the place he work by referencing from the table salary. then i will add all his salary earned all together and insert the total salary for that worker into table work which has the column totalsalary.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SALARYCOUNT ( worker_no IN NUMBER ) RETURN NUMBER IS
wcity WORKDONE.City%TYPE;
wpostal WORKDONE.Postal%TYPE;
total NUMBER:
i INTEGER: = 1;
total_salary NUMBER;
wsalary NUMBER;


BEGIN 

SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO total
FROM WORKDONE
WHERE WorkerNo = worker_no;

WHILE i < total
LOOP

SELECT City,Postal INTO wcity,wpostal FROM WORKDONE WHERE WorkerNo = worker_no;

SELECT Salary INTO wsalary FROM WorkSalary WHERE wcity = City AND wpostal = Postal;

total_salary: =total_salary+wsalary ;

UPDATE WORK SET TotalSalary: = total_salary
WHERE WorkerNo = worker_no;

i: = i+1;

END LOOP;

RETURN(total_salary);

END SALARYCOUNT ;
/
```

function is created with compilation error. i know that if i am able to create the function with no error, my logic of creating this function may be incorrect too. please help me with the error and the logic of the code. i am very new to this.

Comment: Don't use a function to perform DML statements (UPDATE/INSERT etc). Use a procedure. A function is meant to be called in a SQL statement and you can't do DML statements when selecting...

Comment: i need to use as function

Comment: You _cannot_ use it as a function unless you're assigning the return value directly in a PL/SQL block. If you're doing this you can use an OUT parameter as [described in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_6009.htm#SQLRF01309).

Comment: sry forgot to mention,i am doing PLSQL

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, as I say in the comments, don't use a function to perform DML statements (UPDATE/INSERT etc). Use a procedure. A function is meant to be called in a SQL statement and you can't do DML statements when selecting.

Secondly your foreign key on `WORKDONE` is incorrect, you should add both `CITY` and `POSTAL` in the *same* foreign key:

```
CONSTRAINT WORKDONE_FKEY2 FOREIGN KEY (City, Postal)
    REFERENCES WorkSalary(City, Postal)
```

Thirdly, and more of a note for the future, your set-up of your environment is incorrect; it's helpful if you test this before posting a question.

Lastly, there's absolutely no need to use a function to do this. It can all be done in a single [`MERGE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) statement. It's almost always more efficient to use a single SQL statement rather than PL/SQL.

```
 merge into work m
 using ( select wd.workerno, sum(ws.salary) as salary
           from workdone wd
           join worksalary ws
             on wd.city = ws.city
            and wd.postal = ws.postal
          group by wd.workerno ) u
    on (m.workerno = u.workerno)
  when matched then
update
   set m.totalsalary = u.salary;
```

Here's a working [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/76799/1) to demonstrate.

Comment: Whoever set you your homework is not teaching you very well then @user2351750. However, you should easily be able to alter this to work in a function.